# correctly catch an object in typescript catch block

Tags: typescript

I have a function that *could* throw an object as an error. How do I properly handle this in typescript as the object being thrown is not an instance of `Error`

eg:

```
function throwsSomeError() {
  throw { code: 10, message: 'error' }
}

try {
  throwsSomeError()
} catch (error: unknown) {
  const message = error?.message;
  //              ^^ Object is of type 'unknown'.(2571)
}
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAFgJzgdwM4GU4C2ApgKJoZoAUAlIgN4BQiy6W9iEcAJkQFyIBGAAwAaRMWzYAhgHM+iAORFycNAsQBfBloZQ0AT3pMWGHPmJkKNbRylQIKRJWUV+4ANZgsYWo2acwbChxIklZIkQAXkQXVQB+ADoJaTkAbmMAegzmHNy8gD18xAB5ACMAKyJoRBhsRDhgZH0ABwiFDy9MMAUEygAmAFYAdgFqbSA)

Comment: `the object being thrown is not an instance of Error`. What is it?

Comment: This is a new feature of TypeScript 4.4 to make error handling safer : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyBvFey7pVc 

Comment: @ksav the error in this case will be a plain object

Answer (score 0):

https://fettblog.eu/typescript-typing-catch-clauses/

You don't have to specify the type in the catch parameter bracket, then you check the error is what data type in the catch scope.

```
try {
  throwsSomeError()
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof Error) {
    const message = error?.message;
  } else {
    // everything else
  }
}
```

Edit:

Suggest to create a custom error class, so that you can determine the type of object of the error.

```
class CustomError extends Error {
    code?: number
    constructor(code?: number, message?: string) {
        super(message);
        this.code = code
    }
}


function throwsSomeError() {
  throw new CustomError(10, 'error')
}

try {
  throwsSomeError()
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof CustomError) {
    const message = error?.message;
  } else {
    // everything else
  }
}
```

Comment: you can try running this code. the `error instanceof Error` will never be executed since `{ code: 10, message: 'error' }` is not an instance of Error

Comment: I've updated the answer. Thanks for letting me know.